# How to display which function is executing currently at the run time on a lable

Tags: c#-4.0

I am developing windows form application using c#. In my form i have lable and button controls.

In my form i have 3 functions called Function1(),Function2(), Function3().
Each function takes 30 to 50 seconds to for execution.

When i click on button all the three functions executes one after another.

My requirement is i want to display the user which function is currently executing in lable like

1.when executing first function display like MY FIRST FUNCTION IS RUNNING

2.when executing second function display like MY SECOND FUNCTION IS RUNNING

3.when executing third function display like MY third FUNCTION IS RUNNING

After completion of all the three functions i want to display process completed.

In each function i am assigning status to lable control. But it is display my final status only after completion of all the functionality.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `DoEvents` to process any GUI changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=netframework-4.7.2

Run it after you have changed the label text.